# Referencing an object through a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've defined the methods "checkThreshold" and "checkOtherObject" in my prototype.  checkOtherObject iterates across objects listed in attribute "nextDev" and is supposed to invoke checkThreshold for each object, thus:

```
// Protoype
function foo(otherObject) {
    // attributes       
    this.nextDev=otherObject; // comma-delimited list of objects

    // Method that references another method
    this.checkOtherObject= function() {
    successorList=this.nextDev.split(",");
        for (var i=0; i<successorList.length;i++) {
            successorList[i]['checkThreshold']();
        }
    }  
    // Method referenced by checkOtherObject
    this.checkThreshold = function () {
        <Do Stuff>     
    }
//Instantiations
var A = new foo ("B");
var B = new foo ("");
```

Thus, expected behavior is that A.checkOtherObject would invoke B.checkThreshold, but when I get to that line, B.checkThreshold isn't invoked.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't you be calling "successorList[i].checkThreshold();" ?

Comment: @SachinKukreja They're the same thing

Comment: My question is how is this.nextDev anything other than === "B"? Then you're calling .split(",") which just returns "B", so successorList === [ "B" ]. So you are then trying to say "B"['checkThreshold']() which doesn't exist, obviously -- I'm confused..?

Comment: To access the actual B object, you would have to say window[successorList[i]] and call the methods from there -- that is assuming your var A and var B are on the global scope. If not, you will have to reference the scope in which they are defined in

Comment: You should not pass strings around when you want a reference to an object. Instead, use `var b = new Foo(null); var a = new Foo(b)`

Comment: 100% agreed with @Bergi but I figured I would offer an explanation as to why it was functioning the way it was

Comment: @mhodges: `window[successorList[i]]` is what I needed, thanks.  `nextDev` has only one element for simplicity here, but could just as well be "B,C,D,E..."    @Bergi:  I would have thought `var b = new Foo(null)` would instantiate another Foo object instead of referencing an already-existing Foo object.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem: you're trying to assign value of instances in theirselves. Note: what you're doing is still wrong, `otherObject` is a object, but it's a String object and it's not referring to the current *`foo`*'s instance (`this`).

```
this.nextDev = otherObject
```

Other problem is that you're calling *`String().checkThreshold`*, but not *`foo().checkThreshold`*. You can check that at your statements:

```
successorList = this.nextDev.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < successorList.length; i++) {
    successorList[i]['checkThreshold']();
}
```

As you can see you're iterating string literals. *`String().split`* returns a object with string literals back, not a list with *`foo()`'s*.

```
/* confirm that the successorList is a array object */
successorList instanceof Array; // true
/* confirm that the first successorList's item is a string object */
typeof successorList[0] === "string"; // true
```

I'm basically not sure about what's your objective. It looks like you've a extra-ordinary giant confusion between String objects and objects. Maybe you want to store *`nextDev`* out of *`foo()`*, and at *`nextDev`* you want to store a Array object containing instances of *`foo`*? Then try:

```
var devs = [];

function foo(string) {
    devs.push(this);
}

foo.prototype = {
    checkOtherObjects: function() {
        var me = this;
        var myIndex;
        var i = 0, len = devs.length;
        for (; i < len; ++i) {
            if (devs[i] === me) {
                myIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (i = myIndex + 1; i < len; ++i)
            devs[i].checkThresold()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To offer a bit of a better explanation - yes, you **CAN** use `window[successorList[i]]`, however, that is highly, *highly* not recommended, and here's why:

This becomes an issue if the variables no longer in the global scope. For example, if you place the code inside of a function, including an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) or a [document ready](http://www.jstips.co/en/detect-document-ready-in-pure-js/) function, you can no longer reference your variables from the window object, unless you were to declare them with window.A, window.B, but declaring global variables like that  can get so messy, especially when working with other libraries/plugins.

So...how can you work around these issues? Simple - pass the object itself as @Bergi mentioned instead of passing the string that contains the name of the variable.

Here's what the code would look like:

```js
// Protoype
function foo(otherObject) {
    this.nextDev = otherObject || [];
    // Method that references another method
    this.checkOtherObject = function() {
      this.nextDev.forEach(function(obj, index) {
        obj.checkThreshold();
      });
    };
    // Method referenced by checkOtherObject
    this.checkThreshold = function() {
      // Do Stuff
      console.log("Checking Threshold for: ", this);
    };
  }
  //Instantiations
var B = new foo(null);
var A = new foo([B]); //or [B, C, D, E, ...]
A.checkOtherObject();
```